# How to check Node version for a specific project?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have Node version 16.13.1 installed globally in my machine. I have a project where I want to downgrade the version to 14.19.1. I used the command `npm install node@14.19.1 --save-exact` to downgrade, and this version is reflecting in my package.json file.

The problem is, when I run `node -v` at my project's root folder, the version is returned as 16.13.1. To check this, I made an entry in `scripts` in package.json - `"v": "node -v"`. When I run `npm run v`, the output is 14.19.1.

It's clear that my project's Node version was downgraded successfully. So, why does Node show me the global version when I check it from my project's folder? Is there flag to use with `node -v` to check the local version?

Comment: you should use nvm for this purpose.

Comment: You could probably run `npx node -v`.

Comment: @GOTO0 If you add that as an answer, I'll upvote it. Easier than installing NVM.

Comment: @Sh4dy never mind. I'm glad to know that I could help.

Answer (score 4):

To use multiple node versions in your system you have to use nvm. Which is useful to install multiple node versions and easy to switch node versions as per project requirements. [NVM Installation Guid](https://learn2torials.com/a/how-to-install-nvm)

Comment: By using NVM we can use a specific version for each project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NVM](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-version-manager-nvm-install-guide/), it's work for me if you want to use multiple node version